# Unable to select GitHub organization in Azure App Service Deployment Center

Tags: azure, github, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to set up GitHub deployments for an ASP.NET Core web application in Azure App Service Deployment Center.

I'm stuck at the step where I'm supposed to select my GitHub organization - the dropdown is empty:

[image: Deployment Center]

The help says to check Azure App Service permissions on GitHub. However everything looks fine in my `GitHub Setttings > Applications > Authorized OAuth Apps > Azure App Service` (these permissions were automatically set up when I selected GitHub as Source Control in the Deployment Center):

[image: GitHub Settings]

I wasn't able to find any other relevant settings page, neither in the global GitHub settings, nor on the specific repository.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this just took time to propagate. I tried again +- 24 hours later and the dropdowns now seem to be properly poplated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `https://github.com/settings/connections/applications/` find the OAuth App and grant access to the organisation